pygetwindow.PyGetWindowException: Error code from Windows: 258 - The wait operation timed out
When I run this code gw.getWindowsWithTitle(Windows) gets the window but it can't run the game_window[0].activate(). It shows following Error:

pygetwindow.PyGetWindowException: Error code from Windows: 258 - The wait operation timed out.

My code:
 if message.content.startswith('!cmd '):
        cmd = message.content[len('!cmd '):]


        Windows = 'Command Prompt'
        game_window = gw.getWindowsWithTitle(Windows)

        if game_window:
            game_window[0].activate()
            time.sleep(1) 
            pyautogui.typewrite(cmd)
            pyautogui.press('enter')
            await message.channel.send(f'Command "{cmd}" sent to the game window.')
        else:
            await message.channel.send('Game window not found.')

    await bot.process_commands(message)

I tried to handle any exception and make retry mechanics. From second try it gives another ERROR.

pygetwindow.PyGetWindowException: Error code from Windows: 0

I was running cmd with admin privileges.

The final await is still incorrectly indented, and will produce a syntax error.
